# Sitecore index search

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I am building a sitecore index search and its returning results based on the keyword I type in. is there a way that I can know which item has the most hits of the keyword and can sort by using those hits?

```csharp
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("passport_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
    foreach (var t in baseQuery.Split(' '))
    {
        var tempTerm = t;
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Content.Contains(tempTerm));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Martin said - by default it will be ordered by the score descending. But you can also get at the score value by using the `GetResults` extension method.

In your example you would do this:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("passport_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
    foreach (var t in baseQuery.Split(' '))
    {
        var tempTerm = t;
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Content.Contains(tempTerm));
    }
    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate);
    var results = query.GetResults();

    // Get total results
    var total = results.TotalSearchResults;

    var hits = results.Hits.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).Select(x => x.Document);
}
```

The `results.Hits` returns an `IEnumerable<SearchHit<SearchResultItem>>` - the `SearchHit` contains a document, which is the result and a score, which is a float containing the relevancy score for the document.

Answer (score 2):

This is default behaviour, so you shouldn't need to apply a sort.

Results are ordered by their `score`. The major contributing factor to the score is the number of times the term appears in the document.

To quote [the Lucene website](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/scoring.html):

> In general, the idea behind the VSM (Vector Space Modelling) is the
>   more times a query term appears in a document relative to the number
>   of times the term appears in all the documents in the collection, the
>   more relevant that document is to the query.